# How to create dynamic routes that start with a specific character in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I want to create routes that start with **@** symbol how should I structure the `pages` folder? 
first I tried to create a folder with `@` as its name however it will create routes that proceed with `@` like `www.example.com/@/something`. I even tried `[@topic]` and `@[topic]` names for folders but it does not work as expected.

I want to have routes like: 
`www.example.com/@computer`
`www.example.com/@music`
`www.example.com/@programming`

how can I approach the problem?

My `Next.js` version is `9.2.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nico mentioned, We can approach the solution with inspiring from `custom-server` example in `Next.js` repo.

Page's structure will be like this: `page->[topic]`

We need to check inside `server.js` for any incoming request with `URL` that starts with `@` symbol, to do so we'll get help `regular expressions` inside `express.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    // this will match all the URLs that start with @
    // e.g. @computer, @hello
    server.get('/@*', (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, '/[topic]', req.query)
    })


    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err
            console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

This simply coordinates requests that start with `@` to `[topic]` component as before as handling other routes.

Inside component for `client-side` it is as simple as this:

```
 <Link href="/[topic]" as=`@${topicString}`/>
```

You can get `topicString` in different ways like using `query` inside `getInitialProps`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have a custom server, try [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) and some regex. Next.js uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) under the hood.

```js
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:userId(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/:id*',
        destination: "/user/:userId/:id*",
      }
    ]
  }
```

You still will have to sprinkle

```js
 <Link href="/user/[userId]" as=`@${userId}`/>
```

as mentioned by other posters.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the `as` prop of the `Link` component adding the `@` symbol in the place you need it.

For example, if you keep you routes/structure like [the example for dynamic routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing) provided by Next.js, changing the `index.js` under `pages/post/[id]/` to the following:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Header from '../../../components/header'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <h1>Post: {id}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link 
            href="/post/[id]/[comment]" 
            as={`/post/@${id}/first-comment`}>
            <a>First comment</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default Post
```

will give you a URL like this: `http://localhost:3000/post/@first/first-comment`

I hope this helps you find your way.

Comment: thanks, but what if a user entered www.example.com/@computer as a direct link from the browser, then how should I handle the route inside Next.js?

Comment: The above should not be a problem either, if you have a file under `pages` folder named e.g. `[part].js`. Logging `query` on your `getInitialProps` of your `[part].js` will return `{ part: '@computer' }`

Comment: If you have trouble making this work, try to paste a part of your code on your question above, so I can help you further.

Comment: actually what I'm looking for, is some generic way of "pages" structuring that will match URLs start with "@"

Comment: take a look to custom server

Comment: Tnx for your rescuing mention, I got the solution ;) @Nico